# Angular2 Module Http for REST Services not found

Tags: rest, http, meteor, angular

When I'm using Meteor and Angular like it's described in the tutorial there is no Angular2 Module called `Http` to user `REST Services`.

I used below tutorial from ***Meteor*** : 
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping

When I want to import:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
```

and I start meteor, I get this Error Message:

> [web.browser] client/app.ts (5, 36): Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.

Comment: Please improve your question. What tutorial? Add some code that demonstrates what you have tried? Any error messages? ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you put this line in your index.html ?

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js"></script>
```